# Android convert a bitmap to URL

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the url of a bitmap image. I've trued converting it to a uri using:

```
private Uri getImageUri(Context context, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

and

getImageUri(this, image);

But I get an error saying:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   act=inline-data flg=0x1 (has extras) }} to activity
>   {com.example.qrscannertest/com.example.qrscannertest.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString

I don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: Not every bitmap has a url. Are you talking about the **path**?

Comment: @Taslim I don't think so, I'm using an api that needs a URL encoded webaddress url to the image file

Comment: I might be misinterpreting you but.. when I have to send an image-url to an API, I save it in Firebase Storage or GCP, that's the only way I get URLs, I don't think a url is part of the preset properties of an image.